# What is the difference between strtolower and mb_strtolower?

Tags: php, email

In PHP, what is the difference between `strtolower` and `mb_strtolower`?

If I want to convert submitted email address, to be converted to lowercase, which one should I use? Is there any email like this: `Name@Domain-Test.com`

If there are such email, should I still convert the submitted email address to lower case?

Comment: Is this a question about the different between non-mb and mb-functions, or about any mail address?

Answer (score 21):

`strtolower()` doesn't work for Polish chars.

```
<?php strtolower("mĄkA"); ?>
```

will return:

> mĄka

the best solution - use `mb_strtolower()`

```
<?php mb_strtolower("mĄkA",'UTF-8'); ?>
```

will return:

> mąka

See [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower) & [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) in the PHP Manual.

Answer (score 7):

> whats is the different between strtolower and mb_strtolower?

The mb_* functions work with multi-byte string. The manual says:

> By contrast to strtolower(), 'alphabetic' is determined by the Unicode character properties. Thus the behaviour of this function is not affected by locale settings and it can convert any characters that have 'alphabetic' property, such as A-umlaut (Ä).

-

> Is there any email like this : Name@Domain-Test.com

Yes, I suppose there could be email addresses like that. I've found that in general, email addresses are case-insensitive, so I don't bother changing their case.

Comment: i got an email : xxx@Gmail.com

My server cant send email to him. Email sending is auto-generated

Comment: Domains are case-insensitive.  Sending to GoOgLE.com should work just as well as sending to google.com, in theory.

Comment: However, because email addresses are case-insensitive, that means that a user might not always capitalize it the same way, which could cause problems if your login system is comparing their login credentials with an email address in a database in a case-sensitive way.

Answer (score 6):

The mb_ functions work with [Multi-Byte](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php) (unicode) strings as well.  E-Mail addresses shouldn't be case sensitive - there isn't much reason to convert them to lower.

Comment: According to about.com, the "local address" *is* case sensitive, with regards to RFC 2821 (whether or not MTAs treat it that way in practice is another question entirely), while domains are case insensitive.  see: http://email.about.com/od/emailbehindthescenes/f/email_case_sens.htm   As such, best practice is to leave case intact on any address you're planning on using.  Converting to lower case for comparison/assessing uniqueness probably makes sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this function on a unicode string without telling PHP that it is unicode, then you will corrupt your string.  In particular, the uppercase 'A' with tilde, common in 2-byte UTF-8 characters, is converted to lowercase 'a' with tilde.

`mb_strtolower()` is very SLOW, if you have a database connection, you may want to use it to convert your strings to lower case. Even `latin1/9 (iso-8859-1/15)` and other encodings are possible.

Comment: Please credit your sources. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php#78906