# Why should I use strtolower() rather than mb_strtolower()?

Tags: php

I understand the usage/behaviour difference between `strtolower()` and `mb_strtolower()` functions. And it [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866778/php-whats-is-the-different-between-strtolower-and-mb-strtolower) before :)

But I don't understand - what is the current purpose of `strtolower`?

Is it available because of backwards compatibility? Or is there some use cases when `strtolower` is preferable? It seems that `mb_strtolower()` is safer and more versatile so I am tempted to use it everywhere...

Comment: Backward compatibility indeed . mb_strtolower should be prefered as it can work on caracters like 'ç' or 'Ä'

Comment: sometimes php is not compiled with the `Mbstring` functions

Comment: Might be worth nothing strtolower is faster, wouldn't be a deciding factor for most but for some maybe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really backward compatibility, but the ability to use code wihtout additionally loaded multibyte string extension. So a question of portability of the code.

`strtolower()` is always available. `mb_strtolower()` is only available if the additional mbstring module is loaded. The function overloading feature allows to use the "generic" call to `strtolower()` which will actually execute `mb_strtolower()` if configured such. So there actually is no need to explicitly code `mb_strtolower()` at all...

This makes code more portable, since it can run on systems with or without the mbstring extension.

Answer (score 2):

The `strtolower()` is a native function and will always be there compared to `mb_strtolower()` which is only available if the *mbstring* module is installed \ enabled.

But on the question why one should be used over the other, well that is quite simple. You can use them **both** and only use `mb_strtolower()` *when* its needed and or is available.

---

If you script something you should not use **any** special characters in  scripts, filenames, db structures, etc as it should be language independent to improve portability and by doing so it will remove inconsistency's between operating systems. Scripts can behave differently in other environments, for example Linux is case-sensitive on [fs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)/[db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) operations where Windows is not.

A script should **not** *have to deal* with its own special characters as it is unnecessary and it will:

- Cost performance, `strtolower()` is much faster than `mb_strtolower()`
- Lose portability if *mbstring* is not available on the server.

An example is if you use other systems like the [PSR-4 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

```
$var = new \ns\ÇavA();
```

Will attempt to load "Çava.php" instead of "çava.php" because it fails lowering the case due to the fact that its using the native `strtolower()` functions creating an inconstancy. Instead, just keep it ASCII.

---

`mb_strtolower()` should only be used for user input/output where `strtolower()` should be used for system orientated case formatting.

This being said; `strtolower()` will be sufficient for most of anyone's needs, even for user input/output but then the question arises *where* and *how* you apply that data. Keep in mind if its just for output to the user there is always the CSS [text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) method.

Comment: "Linux is case-sensitive where Windows is not" - well, I hope you are talking about file system names only, because in general that is _not_ true. And what is a "special character" exactly please? I mean _if_ you advise against using them, what are they? What is so "special" about them? And the last sentence is, well, let's call it "questionable", shall we?

Comment: @arkascha You were right to question it, I adjusted it to be more specific.

Comment: Em... "ascended characters"? And what about all other 16.4 million non-ascii characters? But ok, lets just drop that issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

- You are not always sure the `mbstring` extension will be available in your environment
- `strtolower()` is significantly faster.

### A bit more

The `mbstring` extension is a non-default PHP extension. This means it is not enabled by default, though in my experience I have never encountered a hosting provider that did not have it enabled.

Your question made me wonder if they would have a difference in performance, so I wrote a quick benchmark function you can find [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d4d62d014cf1cd4c846be51f7b883962f38a3b0).

From the few tests I ran on some random strings, it seems `strtolower()` is **at least 50 times faster** in it's execution.

If you know you are dealing with strings that are compatible with `strtolower()` and you have a really big amount of them, it may be worth examining `strtolower()` instead.